# Vibrate smartwatch

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I would like to confirm an action that I done on my smartphone (for example when sending an email) by doing some vibration on my smartwatch.

In my MainActivity (when email is send) I have :

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, HelloExtensionService.class);
serviceIntent.setAction(HelloExtensionService.INTENT_ACTION_SEND);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

I understand throught an example that I have to override onStartCommand in a class who extends ExtensionService :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     Intent i = new Intent(Control.Intents.CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT);
 i.setPackage("com.example.hellosmartwatch");
 sendBroadcast(i);
}

@Override
public ControlExtension createControlExtension(String hostAppPackageName) {
        boolean advancedFeaturesSupported = DeviceInfoHelper.isSmartWatch2ApiAndScreenDetected(this, hostAppPackageName);
        if (advancedFeaturesSupported) {
            return new Vibrator(this,hostAppPackageName, new Handler());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I know I have to use ControlExtension, in my case Vibrator.class and so I override the method onStart() :

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
startVibrator(500, 300, 2);
}
```

But it doesn't work. What I miss or I don't understand for have something that work.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if what you want to do is use the notification extension instead of the control extension. This will vibrate the watch for you as well as keep a quick track record of previous events. I would recommend the HelloNotification Sample in the Sony Add-On SDK if you need an example of this type of extension. Otherwise if you use the Control extension you will have to start the app on the SmartWatch run the vibration command and then stop the app. Does that sound like it could work for you?